# Array overwriting(?) in OpenMP

Tags: openmp

As an introduction to OpenMP, I'm trying to print a list of prime numbers.

```
// compile: gcc primes.c -fopenmp -o primes
#include <stdio.h>  //printf()
#include <stdlib.h> //atoi() and malloc()

//#define ARR_MAX 1000

int isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    if (argc < 2 || !(n = atoi(argv[1]))) // || n >= ARR_MAX)
        return 0;

    // int arr[ARR_MAX];
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 1));
    int counter = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for shared(arr)
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            arr[counter] = i;
            printf("%2d  ", arr[counter]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        printf("%2d  ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(arr);
}
```

I print the results twice.

- When they're first calculated and written, everything looks good.
- Later on, when I try to print what was saved, things have gone wrong somehow.

Here's the same example, run 6 times:

```bash
$ ./primes 55
 2   3   5   7  11  13  17  19  23  43  47  53  29  31  37  41
43   3   5   7  11  13   1  19  23   0  47  53  33605084  31  37  41
$ ./primes 55
29  31  37  41   2   3   5   7  11  13  43  47  53  17  19  23
43  31  37  41  43   3   5   7  11  13   9  47  53   0  19  23
$ ./primes 55
 2   3   5   7  11  13  29  31  37  41  17  19  23  43  47  53
43   3   5   7  11  13   1  31  37  41   9  19  23   0  47  53
$ ./primes 55
29  31  37  41  43  47  53   2   3   5   7  11  13  17  19  23
43  31  37  41  43  47  53   0   3   5   7  11  13   0  19  23
$ ./primes 55
43  47  53  17  19  23   2   3   5   7  11  13  29  31  37  41
43  47  53   0  19  23   1   3   5   7  11  13  33605084  31  37  41
$ ./primes 55
29  31  37  41   2   3   5   7  11  13  43  47  53  17  19  23
43  31  37  41  43   3   5   7  11  13   9  47  53   0  19  23
```

I'm currently using malloced array, just to avoid having a max. But I also tried it with a static array. The code is still there, commented out, if you want to inspect it or try it. The same problem was present then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a **race condition** in your code: you cannot safely do `counter++` and `arr[counter] = i` in this parallel loop because multiple thread can find primes at the same time.

A simple way to fix this is to use a **critical section** (with `#pragma omp critical` so the content of the condition is executed by one thread at a time and `counter` is protected. This is not so bad when `n` is large since there are not a lot of prime number compared to classical numbers (AFAIK `O(n/log(n))` prime numbers). This solution is certainly the best on platforms with few cores.

An alternative solution is to use **atomics** (wit `#pragma omp atomic`), but they are not far better than a lock here on most mainstream architecture.

Another solution is to write the prime number found in a **thread-local buffer** and then **copy it in a shared buffer**. That being said, the order is not preserved. You can restore the order using a sort, but sorting algorithms tends to be a bit slow. A parallel sort can be relatively fast, but hard to implement efficiently.

A last solution is to allocate a 8-bit **mask array** of size `n` initialized to 0 and flag prime numbers by setting the value to 1. This solution is certainly the best on many-core platforms. You can then travel the mask array to find the prime numbers. This can even be done in parallel in two steps: 1 parallel reduction to count the number of values and one to fill the final array containing prime numbers.

Also please note that the order of `printf` calls is not deterministic in a parallel loop.

Comment: The flag approach worked beautifully. It almost seems too simple somehow, like it's cheating XD